# Datetime as arrays and convert dateformat and insert into database

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I'm importing data from CSV file into database through HTML form, having multiple datetime in format `23/06/2015 12:00` which i convert to `2015-23-06` with follwing code

```
$Datetime = $emapData['1']; //Format is 23/06/2015 12:00
$ConvertDatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $Datetime);
$NewDatetime = new DateTime($ConvertDatetime);
$NewDate = $NewDatetime->format('Y-m-d'); Here I have date in desire format (2015-06-23)
$NewTime = $NewDatetime->format('H:i'); Here I have time in format (7:00)
```

One solution is that i repeat above code by changing variables name to convert other datetime in csv which i did and things working fine but I'm thinking to use arrays, load the datetime into arrays and then convert datetime and then insert converted datetime into database.

```
$DateTimeArray = array( 
    '2/17/2015 13:59', '2/20/2015 18:59', '2/05/2015 05:59', '2/15/2015 03:59', '2/19/2015 12:59', '2/10/2015 14:59'
);
```

and then foreach

```
foreach ($DateTimeArray as $DateTime){ 
    $ConvertDatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $DateTime);
    $NewDatetime = new DateTime($ConvertDatetime);
    $NewDate = $NewDatetime->format('Y-m-d');
    $NewTime = $NewDatetime->format('H:i');
    $ConvertedDateTime = $NewDate . " " . $NewTime;
    $FinalDateTime[] = $ConvertedDateTime;
}
print_r($FinalDateTime);
```

but the ouput is just this current datetime

```
Array ( [0] => 2015-07-23 20:44 [1] => 2015-07-23 20:44 [2] => 2015-07-23 20:44 [3] => 2015-07-23 20:44 [4] => 2015-07-23 20:44 [5] => 2015-07-23 20:44 )
```

need help to sort it out.

Comment: The format you use in your `createFromFormat()` method call bears little resemblance to the format you're passing in for the date.... mask values are case sensitive, `d` !== `D`, etc; you completely ignore the time.... suggest you read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the relevant format masking characters

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry it was typo mistake

Comment: @MarkBaker if i add time like this `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i', $DateTime);` i get error `Exception: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: @shehary yes, because of this line ~ `$NewDatetime = new DateTime($ConvertDatetime);`. `$ConvertDatetime` is already a `DateTime` instance, that's what `createFromFormat` returns

Comment: @Phil i sorted the issue and checked in fiddle after your suggestion in comment, can you make it answer so it help future user

Comment: @Phil can you please make the answer you suggested in comment

Comment: Eh, I just voted to close as *"a typo or no longer a problem"*

Comment: okey, now what can i say :) but it wasn't just a typo.